# Is this function continous across the plane given the following conditions apply? ( - or will the partial derivatives affect continuity?)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I've been given this question:
$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, s.t:

- for every $x_0$ $f(x_0,y)$ is continuous with respect to y.
- for every $y_0$ $f(x,y_0)$ is continuous with respect to x.
- the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist for every $(x,y)$ 

   is $ f$ continous at every $(x,y)?$ 
  I know that had the partial derivative condition not been a part of $f$'s attributes the answer would've been no, so my question is - does the last attribute change f's continuity? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is meant as a comment - the Add Comment link isn't working...)

You say you "know" it's false without the last condition. Have you tried simply looking at the counterexample to see whether it satisfies the last condition?

Comment: Thanks - that's a great Idea. I've tried looking at how this question differs from the one I already know how to solve and tried approaching from the angle of looking at the properties of partial derivatives and maybe proving it/disproving it that way. I'll try to find a counter-example, thanks!

Comment: update - hey I found the counter example used, it's $$f(x) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}$$ at every point except $(0,0)$, $f(0,0)=0$. I'm struggling with calculating the partial derivatives using it though

Comment: i think i got it! will post a solution